# HandleBars Check if Index in Each is Divisible by four

Tags: handlebars.js, jsreport

Not very familiar with handlebars, but I'm using it in a reporting setting, and working with output intended to be printed. The document I'm printing should be four per page, so I want to do a check like `if(index%4 === 0)` but I'm a little unsure of how to do it.

I'm going through an array of objects with `{{#each dataset}}`

here is the basic layout, and my attempt for my four-per-page report.

```
<div class="container">
    {{#each Badges}}
    <div class='cardContainer'>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="leftCard">
                <p>{{Event}}</p>
                <p>{{Email}}</p>
                <p>{{Name}}</p>
                <p>{{Address}}</p>
                <p>{{City}} {{State}} {{Zip}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rightCard">
                <h4 class='eventTitle'>{{Event}}</h4>
                <h2>{{Name}}
                    <br>
                    <span style='font-size: 26pt'>{{City}} <br> {{State}}</span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{#if @index%4 === 0}}
        </div><div class="container">
    {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

The Container will have margins and padding set properly, and each of the reports are contained within the `.card` class, and the `.container` class is for the pagination.

What should go in the IF?

**This is going to go into [jsreport](http://jsreport.net/) which I'm also not fully familiar with. Not sure if I can register a helper.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) does not have a lot of built-in support for logic. If your template requires some simple math, you are going to have to create one or more [helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers).

In your case, you need to add `1` to your `@index` and determine if this result is evenly divisible by your desired page size of `4`.

In the interest of having our helpers do one thing, I would recommend splitting this functionality into two helpers; I will call them `sum` and `isDivisor`.

`sum` will take any number of Numbers as arguments and return the result of adding them all together:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('sum', function () {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).reduce((acc, num) => acc += num);
});
```

`isDivisor` will take two Numbers as arguments and will return `true` if the first Number is a [divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) of the second; otherwise `false`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isDivisor', function (num1, num2) {
    return num1 !== 0 && num2 % num1 === 0;
});
```

Handlebars' [subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) are delimited by parentheses, so what should go in your IF is the following:

```
{{#if (isDivisor 4 (sum @index 1))}}
```

For reference, I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/npfa0wp1/).

**However, although the above answers your question, I believe there is a better way to solve your problem.**

I think the better solution would be to create a [block helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) that will slice your Array into chunks of your desired page size and then apply a template to each chunk, before concatenating and rendering the result. Such an implementation would look like the following:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('page', function (arr, pageSize, options) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += pageSize) {
        result.push(options.fn({ items: arr.slice(i, i + pageSize) }));
    }
    return result.join('');
});
```

The `options.fn` bit is the interesting part. It is applying our template block to a data object with a single property, `items`, which is a paged slice of our original array. The way we would use this helper in our template is as follows:

```
{{#page Badges 4}}
    <div class="container">
        {{#each items}}
            <div class="cardContainer">
                {{! TODO: Copy inner template and paste here. }}
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/page}}
```

For reference, I have created *another* [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/nhd6uz1c/).