# HandleBars - Each Loop - Display four at a time

Tags: loops, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

Using HandleBars.

I have 8 items. I want to display 4 items, then display another 4 items.

```
1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8
```

My code so far:

```
{{#each item}}
{{#if @index '<' 4}}
{{@index}}
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

So, I have restricted my code to only show 4, but I am struggling to expand on this and loop through the remaining four items.

I know this is noob question, literally just learning HandleBars.

Any advice is helpful and appreciated. Much love all.

Comment: I once answered a question that was very similar to yours. Take a look and see if this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46616030/3397771

Answer (score 0):

```html
{{#each item}}
{{#if @index '<' 4}}
{{@index}}
{{else}}                        //add else
 {{@index}}     
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however this doesn't quite work. I'll need to start the 'else' code from the 5th item index