# implement pagination and the loading spinner to append element (multiple tabs)

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am new to javascript and creating the 2 tab to display the data. It is using the handlebar template and pure javascript. I want to add the loading spinner before the data is loaded in each tabs. How can implement the loading spinner to the multiple tabs when the data is retrieved using append method. i try to add the loading spinner but it always show the loading spinner eventhough the data has been loaded and displayed.
When i try to add loading spinner it got the error of 'Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null'
 Any help will be appreciate. Below is the code without implement the loading spinner

```js
function reload_api(){
      let source = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
      let template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      let html = template(data_api.data);
      document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
      render_tab_contents();
      document.getElementById("index-0").click();
    }

        function tab_contents() {
    //this part is to display the data (tab content)
            data_api.data.dropdown.forEach((agoptions) => {
                data_api.data.fyafyidropdown.forEach((dropOptions) => {       
                    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data_api.data.listing)) {
                        let groupName = `dropdowngroup_${agoptions.ag_id}_${agoptions.ad_id}_${dropOptions.value}`;
                        if (key == groupName) {                         document.getElementById(`ag_${agoptions.ag_id}_${agoptions.ad_id}`); 
                            for (const [key1, val1] of Object.entries(value)) {
                                if (key1 != 'more_url') {
                                    let contents = document.createElement('div');
                                    contents.innerHTML ='<div class="line text-gray-500 flex flex-col divide-black divide-y-2 divide-opacity-25"><div class="flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer p-2 transition duration-200 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100 hover:shadow-xl" ><div class="flex flex-col items-start">' + '<p class="font-semibold pb-1">' +val1.mail_serial_no + '</p><p class="pb-1 text-sm">'+ val1.mail_subject +  '</p><div class="flex items-center pb-1"></div></div>'+ '<div class="flex-none"><div class="flex flex-col text-sm"><p class="px-2 py-1 font-semibold ">' +  val1.pending_count + '</p></div></div></div></div>';                  document.getElementById(`ag_${agoptions.ag_id}_${agoptions.ad_id}`).appendChild(contents);                       
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                if(document.getElementById(`ag_${agoptions.ag_id}_${agoptions.ad_id}`).innerHTML == ''){
                                       document.getElementById(`ag_${agoptions.ag_id}_${agoptions.ad_id}`).innerHTML = '<div class="flex justify-center mt-4">No Records</div>';
                }
            });
        }

        function open(evt, Name) {

          var i, tabcontent, tablinks; 
          tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
          for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
          }

          tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
          for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }

          document.getElementById(Name).style.display = "block";
          evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebar-template" id="template">
        <div class="tab">
          <div class="mb-1">
            <div class="flex text-center text-gray-400">
            {{#each dropdown}}
              <button class="tablinks  flex-1 py-2 px-4 border-b-2 cursor-pointer " id="index-{{@index}}" onclick="open(event, 'ag_{{ag_id}}_{{ad_id}}')">{{full_name}}</button>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
          </div></div>
    
          {{#each dropdown}}
            <div id="agency_{{ag_id}}_{{ad_id}}" data-scope="ag_{{ag_id}}_{{ad_id}}" class="tabcontent">
      //here is the data displayed. the data is retrieved and displayed using the javascript in tab_contents() //
    </div>
          {{/each}}
        </script>
        <div id="contents"></div>
// Here is the sample data from api   
//data: {,…}
//dropdown: [{ag_id: "60", ad_id: "1", agency_short_name: "HQ", agency_full_name: "HQ",…},…]
//fyafyidropdown: [{label: "FYA", value: "fya"}, {label: "FYI", value: "fyi"}]
//listing: {agadgroup_60_1_fya: {,…},…}
//group_60_1_fya: {,…}
//group_60_1_fyi: {0: {mail_serial_no: "(Filing)", mail_subject: "123", pending_count: 1,…},…}
```

Comment: Would this be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46616030/3397771 ?

Comment: no because the data in tabs is retrieved using appendchild method directly in javascript. and I want to show the page number button.

Comment: I find it too difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Would you be able to simplify this code, or provide more explanation?

Comment: for example, i want to display only 5 data on each page

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two lists of data and you render each into an HTML element and you show one element or the other depending on which of two tab buttons was last clicked. If you would like to paginate each of those lists, then you would slice each list into sublists of 5 and determine which slice to show based on which corresponding button was last clicked. The logic for the pagination buttons would be very similar to what you have done for your tabs.

Comment: yes, but i don’t really don’t know how to add the pagination.because the data is retrieved using append method and also i am quite blur for the javascript